# CSS file either deleted or is hidden in atom

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, atom-editor

I have been learning for just over a month now and I started my first project and I was coming to a close with it and literally last sec the CSS file is blank. I am using chrome and atom text editor. I did not have my git acc linked to it so history is not saved on it. The only thing showing on the file for the class is "
1
*
*
*
*
*
"
When I hit backspace it takes forever to delete because I'm pretty sure my code is just hidden there or something. I have no idea what happened. I spent some hours trying to fix it but no dice.

Comment: Not all HTML files have CSS files. Did you actually create a CSS file and type commands into it?  If so, did you save it? since no CSS file, is there a line in your HTML file where you call the CSS file. if not I'd assume you don't need one.

Answer (score 0):

#### Have you tried opening the file in explorer?

- If you right click on your project folder there is an option to open in file explorer. **(This may say "Show in file manager" if you're using the latest version of Atom)**
- Check if the file is there, if it is, try opening it notepad or another simple text editor.
- If it's not there it may have been corrupted, I've used atom quite a bit and never encountered this problem.
- If it is, you can always just delete the file in your project folder and make a new one, pasting the contents in from when you opened it in notepad.